# With node.js / express-session is it possible to save() just one property on the session?

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

**Environment:** Node.js, Express, express-session

**Question:** Is it possible to save just one property of a session instead of saving over the entire session?

**Background:** Normally [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) saves the session at the end of each http response,  i.e. when the route is finished.  However it's possible to save a session at any time with `req.session.save()`.  This saves the entire session.  Normally that's not a problem but I have a use case where that is a problem.

**Explanation:** In the code below I pass `req` to `subfunction`.  This function alters a property on the session and then saves the session with `req.session.save()`.  Unfortunately when I passed `req` into `subfunction` `req.session.myProperty` was set to true.  When I save the session it stores true when in the main route that property has already been changed to false.  In `subfunction` what I need to do is update `req.session.someOtherProperty` and then only save that single property.  Is that possible?

**Example:**

```
function myRoute(req, res) {
  
    req.session.myProperty = true;

    subFunction(req);  // runs in the background while the route continues.

    req.session.myProperty = false;    

    // do more stuff and return

}

function async subFunction(req) {

    // uh oh, req.session.myProperty was passed in as true.
    // In the main route it's already been changed to false.

    let testURLResult = await testIfURLActive('www.example.com'); 

    req.session.testURLResult = testURLResult;
    req.session.save(); // I need it to save just req.session.testURLResult, not the entire session.

    // req.session.myProperty was just saved as true because that's what passed in.  When I save it overwrites the false value that was set in the main route.

    return;

}
```

Comment: What does "runs in the background while the route continues" mean?  Please show the ACTUAL code that causes that to happen.

Comment: Javascript, like any other programming language, is 100% synchronous. So as written `subFunction` does not run in the background. Also, javascript, just like Java, Python, C++, C# etc. have the ability to make asynchronous I/O requests. The main difference is that I/O is asynchronous by default in javascript but synchronous by default in other languages. So, unless `subFunction` makes an asynchronous I/O request (not shown in the example) it will run fully synchronous before returning

Comment: @jfriend00  Sorry about that I neglected to show that subFunction was `async`.  I updated the question.

Comment: I still can't tell what problem you're trying to solve.  Set the properties you want on the session object and/or remove the properties you don't want and call `req.session.save()`.   What else are you trying to do besides that?  And, of course, the `req.session.myProperty = false` will happen before your `req.session.save()` because as soon as `subFunction()` hits the `await` in it, then it returns a promise and `req.session.myProperty = false` gets to run.  Calling `subFunction()` and ignoring the promise it returns is likely a programming mistake.

Comment: @jfriend00 In the real version it can take several minutes to test the URLs.  The client has finished the main route and probably visited several other routes by the time the URL tests have finished in the background.  Perhaps a dozen session variables have changed by then.  When the test is complete and the result is saved to the session it is saving the original req.session that was passed in when the async function was called, not the session still being used by the client 5 routes away.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: OK, I offered my ideas in an answer below.  It took awhile to understand what was causing the actual problem here.  The "several minutes" was the missing clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so I think I'm finally understanding that the problem is that you have an asycnhronous operation that can take a while to run and when it's done you want to save one particular property in the session so it persists for future requests.

But, if you use the `req.session` object you have, update that one property and call `req.session.save()` on that, you will be saving a stale session object that may overwrite other properties that have legitimately been changed by other requests while this long running request was running.

The two ways I can think of to save just your one new property are:

1. Directly access the session store and update just that one property in the session store.
2. Ask express-session to get you a new, updated `req.session`, modify your one property and then call `req.session.save()` on that newly updated session object.

Since you don't show anything about what type of session store you're using, I'll focus on the second option here.  You can do that by removing the current `req.session` and calling the session middleware again which will essentially fetch a new, ***fresh*** copy of the session.

You don't show your session initialization code, but let's just take an example from the doc of this:

```
app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));
```

So, first change that to this:

```
const sessionMiddleware = session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
});
app.use(sessionMiddleware);
```

We need to save a copy of the session middleware so we can invoke it manually later.

Then, in your long running function, you can use that like this:

```
// note I am passing res and next here now too
async function subFunction(req, res, next) {
    let testURLResult = await testIfURLActive('www.example.com'); 

    // remove the current session object from req to we can obtain a fresh one
    delete req.session;
    // repopulate req.session
    sessionMiddleware(res, req, err => {
        if (err) {
            next(err);
            return;
        }
        // fresh req.session here
        req.session.testURLResult = testURLResult;
        req.session.save();        
    });
}
```

Note, there are other issues here that should also be addressed:

1. You have no error handling for `testIfURLActive()` or for calling `subFunction()`.  If either can ever reject, then you will have an unhandled rejection which will terminate your server in the latest version of node.js.  You need to catch rejections there unless that can never reject.
2. Because the modified `subFunction()` needs to be able to act as full-blown middleware, I am now passing `req, res, next` to it.  You will need to modify where you call it to also do that.

Comment: Thanks jfriend00!  I stripped out the error handling to keep my question short.  I'm going to try it your way.  That blows my mind that I can call the sessionMiddleware function and it knows how to grab the correct, current session.  I'm using the default store on my Windows system for development.  On the release version the server sits on a Linux box and I use Redis to store the session.

Comment: @myNewAccount - You calling it manually and passing the current `req, res` is the same as what `app.use(...)` does.  You're just doing it manually after you've removed the session and asking it to do its normal job again.

Comment: Is it theoretically possible that this could result in a collision or is that not possible because Node executes my entire subFunction before it goes back and processes something else?  For example if I grab the latest session is it possible (even though it's highly unlikely) for the client in the very next instant to make a choice that changes a session value and thus I'm stuck saving a stale session after the fact?  Or would Node handle the entire subFunction before it processes something else from the client?  In that case it's 100% safe.

Comment: @myNewAccount - That's a bit of a complicated question.  Nodejs runs your Javascript in a single thread so your `subFunction()` code will execute continuously without interruption until you get to an asynchronous operation like your `await`.  At that point (during the `await`) other code can run.  Then, inside of express-session, it's also possible that there is an asynchronous break and other code could run during that. It would be more likely with an external database-backed store than using the default memory store. But, this code is drastically reducing the possibility of a race condition.

Comment: @myNewAccount - express-session does not have a good overall design for preventing race conditions.  It generally assumes that you won't have multiple requests from the same client (and thus using the same session) that do longer running asynchronous operations that modify the session after their longer running asynchronous operation.   Because as you've seen, when you do that, you run a decent chance of overwriting someone else's changes with stale values.  This change I suggested reduces the race condition to a very small window of time.

Comment: @myNewAccount - To get rid of the race condition entirely, you would need to store critical data in a database directly using the appropriate concurrency features of the target database (such as locks or atomic update operations) so no request handler is fetching data, holding onto it for awhile, then modifying the potentially older data and then writing that stale data.

Comment: @myNewAccount - FYI, another strategy for dealing with session race conditions is to create a session-specific request queue so a 2nd request attempting to use the session is forced to wait until the first one is done and so on...  This could be useful if it isn't a required and expected feature to run multiple long running requests from the same client that all modify the session and you're just trying to prevent unexpected edge case session race conditions.